# page creation with ionic version 4

Tags: ionic-framework

Hello dear community currently I work on my portfolio but with the version 4 of ionic I manage not to generate a new page by typing the command ionic generate page Contact.
Someone could help me

Voila l'erreur aprés avoir lancer la commande : 
$ ionic generate page realisations

> ng generate page realisations
>   Could not find module "@ionic/angular-toolkit" from "C:\wamp64\www\fil_Rouge\portfolioV4".
>   Error: Could not find module "@ionic/angular-toolkit" from "C:\wamp64\www\fil_Rouge\portfolioV4".
>       at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Stagiaire\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
>       at NodeModulesEngineHost._resolvePackageJson (C:\Users\Stagiaire\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\node-module-engine-host.js:28:21)
>       at NodeModulesEngineHost._resolveCollectionPath (C:\Users\Stagiaire\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\node-module-engine-host.js:69:40)
>       at NodeModulesEngineHost.createCollectionDescription (C:\Users\Stagiaire\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\file-system-engine-host-base.js:111:27)
>       at SchematicEngine._createCollectionDescription (C:\Users\Stagiaire\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:147:40)
>       at SchematicEngine.createCollection (C:\Users\Stagiaire\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:140:43)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like there are a bunch of missing modules from your ionic installation. I recommend uninstalling ionic globally, re-installing it and then starting a new project. After that, move into the directory of the new project and come back with the output of the ionic info command.

Commands for reference:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic (Uninstalling Ionic from machine)

npm install -g ionic (Installing it globally)

ionic start blank myApp (starting new app)

cd myApp (change directory to application Mac/Linux/Windows Powershell)

ionic info (Get ionic information )
```